# Workbox generating multiple unformatted service worker files

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, workbox, micro-frontend

When i use either of the 3 methods : workbox-cli, workbox webpack build or node generate, to generate service worker files using workbox, i get 4 unformatted files instead of a single formatted service worker file which i can verify for correctness. I followed workbox documentation and also many youtube tutorials. I tried with multiple versions of workbox as well. Still, i am getting the same result. I am getting 4 unformatted files (2 of them have random generated hash value) which i cannot make sense of.

Please help me in understandoing why this is happening. Also help me in understanding if there are any better alternatives as well.

Answer (score 1):

When using workbox build, the behaviour that you're seeing has to do with the default settings. In the workbox build configuration object (I'm not sure how webpack exposes this since I'm using rollup) setting the `mode` parameter to anything except `"production"` will result in a human readable service worker file (a minimized service worker is the default). To get rid of the extra `worker_[hash].js` files that get created, you need to set the `inlineWorkboxRuntime` option to `true` (`false` is the default). Finally, if you're seeing source map files being generated, you need to set the `sourcemap` option to `false`. With these settings you should get a single human readable service worker .js file.